# Get transactions for an address

Tags: web3.js

Is there a js api that can retrieve recent transactions of a Wallet? Couldn't find such thing on web3.js.

Would be cool if someone could share a workaround!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [connection.getSignatureForAddresses](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getSignaturesForAddress) to get  confirmed signatures for transactions involving an address.

Then use the [connection.getTransactions](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransactions) to get the transactions for the given signatures.

```
const address = new PublicKey("...");
const connection = new Connection("...");

async function getTransactionsForAddress(address) {
  const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(address);
  const transactions = awiat connection.getTransactions(signatures);

  console.log({transactions});
  return transactions;
};

getTransactionsForAddress(address);
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated your code so would be helpful to others:
```
export const getTransactionsForAddress = async(address: string)=> {
    let connection = await getConnection();
    const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(new solana.PublicKey(address));
    let temp: any[] = []; // just a temp array to get the signatures
    signatures.map((x) => temp.push(x.signature));

    const transactions = await connection.getTransactions(temp);
    return transactions;
}
```

Comment: looks ugly, will post separately

Answer (score 1):

thanks to C.OG:

```
export const getTransactionsForAddress = async(address: string)=> {
    let connection = await getConnection();
    const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(new solana.PublicKey(address));
    let temp: any[] = []; // just a temp array to get the signatures
    signatures.map((x) => temp.push(x.signature));

    const transactions = await connection.getTransactions(temp);
    return transactions;
}
```

can def be improved, but gets the job done