# Why explorers not supporting transaction pagination? Why is it impossible to see the first tx of an account

Tags: solscan, explorers

I'm wondering why no solana explorer shows the entire number of transactions like etherscan. For example, it is impossible to see the first transaction of a solana account with hundreds of thousands of transactions! Is this because of NONCE?

Solana explorers:
[image]

etherscan:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a Solana or Ethereum reason for this. For both Ethereum and Solana you can't directly fetch the first transaction of an account, instead you have to iterate backwards through all transactions until you stop finding transactions for an address. I assume in the case of Etherscan they do this process on the backend and store it so that the frontend can just query it from there & that Solscan doesn't support this feature on the backend.

Comment: So all this to say if this a feature you'd like you should ping the Solscan team on Twitter or discord :)

Comment: so if I have a solana full node locally, how long will it take me to get all transactions of an account with 200k transactions?

Comment: You don't need a full node for this - you can just use web3js on your local machine: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/get-transactions-for-an-address . The time it takes to execute then depends on the speed of your RPC.